# facebook C# sdk- comparing from id and userid

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-3.5, facebook-graph-api

using feed dialogue i m posting some data to wall using my app..
but when my friend go to view this feed , its shows the app for itself only..
the reason is i am checking the from id parameter in request.params bt since i m using access token to access user info in graph api, it overlaps the previous params and only code with access token is dere in request..

how to resolve it..??

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. You show the post to feed dialog to the user and then? Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont get what you're asking about exactly , but if you post anything to any user's wall, you should get authorized first, and i think you know that already as you mentioning.

So after you get the access token, you can do that to post anything to the user's wall, assuming that you're using Facebook C# SDK as mentioned in the title:

> FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient("AccessToken"); //replace your access token with that..
>
> dynamic me = fbClient.Get("/me");
>   Dictionary data = new Dictionary();
>   data.Add("message", txtStatusContent.InnerText.Trim());
>
> fbClient.Post("/me/feed", data);

And that's it.